# degrees of freedom in vector fitting using envfit (vegan)

Tags: r, vegan

I used the envfit() in the vegan package to determine the environmental gradients controlling the 2 NMDS axes. I had 2 categorical environmental (factors) and 4 continuous variables (vectors).

My question is does vector fitting give degrees of freedom? If yes, how and where do I find it? If no, why not?

Answer (score 0):

It does not as `envfit` is a purely correlative approach. You can test as many variables as you want with `envfit`, the ordination won't change and the fit of the other variables won't change.

Comment: then is the r2 in the results a correlation coefficient, if so, which one? or is it the usual R square as in explanatory power/goodness of fit?

Comment: I assume you understand that it is both: it is the square of correlation coefficient **and** the usual measure of "goodness of fit". There is an arrow, you project your points to that arrow and calculate a correlation between projected positions and the variable. To see how this works, use `ordisurf` with argument `knots = 1`.